# Is having an XSD considered good practice when passing XML marshalled objects across the wire?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, jaxb

I'm using a mix of JAXB, JPA, and a RESTful web service to pass objects across the wire. My domain objects contain a mix of JPA and JAXB annotations, and I'm able to successfully unmarshall my domain objects using Spring's RestTemplate with a minimum amount of code. I remember reading something not too long ago (may have been an answer on SO, may have been a blog) where the author argued that he would never rely on annotations in a production environment, but always marshall and unmarshall according to a schema. Is this still a necessary practice?

If I have a .jar with annotated beans that is a dependency in two projects (e.g. the producing RESTful web service and the consuming client), wouldn't introducing generated XSDs effectively add another set of data requiring maintenance? When using annotated JAXB POJOs, when are schemas necessary and what benefit do they provide?

Comment: This isn't really java or JAXB-specific, this is a more general question of best practice with XML-over-HTTP applications.

Comment: I partially agree, though the presence of JAXB-specific annotations is very relevant to my question. It is a question about best practices, but within the J2EE ecosystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAXB represents its metadata as annotations so there really is no marshal/unmarshal according to the XML schema.

I lead the JAXB component ([MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)) of [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org), which is best know for its [JPA implementation](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/jpa.php).  My recommendation for developers is to use a combination of JAXB & JPA annotations on their model.

**Uses of XML schema:**

- As [mentioned by biziclop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794272/is-having-an-xsd-considered-good-practice-when-passing-xml-marshalled-objects-acr/4794403#4794403) JAXB can leverage the XML Schema during marshal/unmarshal operations to perform validation.
- The XML schema also provides a means for clients of your RESTful service to know what the expected XML message looks like.  As [mentioned by Fabian Steeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794272/is-having-an-xsd-considered-good-practice-when-passing-xml-marshalled-objects-acr/4794440#4794440) you can make the schema easier to maintain by having it created as part of your build.

Answer (score 1):

In dev and test environment schema validation can be quite useful (detecting different versions of the code, for example), in production you'd better switch it off. Unless the system you're communicating with is developed by someone else, in which case an XSD validation can help shift the blame quickly and efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all users of the services are Java clients I agree it doesn't get you much and only adds additional maintenance effort. If you plan to have non-Java clients however, generating XSDs (possibly as part of the automated build, which would minimize the maintenance overhead) makes sense.